# Tomcat HTTP error 505 - white space - error handling

Tags: java, http, tomcat, error-handling

I get HTTP error 505 in Tomcat since the client sends a request with a whitespace.
(See [HTTP error code 505](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734205/http-error-code-505)).

This is easy to fix this by encoding the request but since we have no way to change the client, I would like to know if there is a possibility to handle this in Tomcat. (i.e HTTP connector still passing the request to the servlet that would handle the error).
Thank you.