# I get 500 (Internal Server Error) but still show json result, why?

Tags: php, nginx, drupal-7, http-status-code-500

I have a test server and 2 test domains, but I get this problem but I can't explain.
My server : Nginx
PHP 5

Check status by Browser : chrome

```
> 505 error but still get result : 
>     
>         http://trangantravel.vn/autocomplete_deluxe/taxonomy/field_length/%20/10?term=&synonyms=0
>         
>         200 Status ok, same Ip
>         http://phutungoto.zapto.org/vi/autocomplete_deluxe/taxonomy/field_loai_phu_tung/%20/10?term=&synonyms=0
```

Can you explain why I still get result (json) meanwhile I get 500 error status?

Comment: Probably the issue resulting in the error takes place _after_ the response has been send.

Comment: @arkascha, do you have any idea to fix it, can I bypass 500 error in this case?

Comment: Well, for that we obviously wound need to see 1. the precise error message from the http servers log file and 2. the actual code that lead to the error.

Comment: I think my server is ok because the second one is ok, I think I got problem with code with the frist one.

Comment: Which is a comment that does not help at all, since 1. it does not react in any way to what I wrote before and 2. no one knows what that actually is meant to say.

Comment: well, looks like a `505` to me, `Unsupported HTTP version`.  Follow **[this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734205/http-error-code-505)** to see if any of the answers may apply to your failing request.