# getting 505 responce from server

Tags: java, android, apache, http-status-code-505

Hi in my android project i m calling a webservice and sending get parameter through query string parameter , now problem is that if query string parameter value contains any white space then i am getting 505 error

```
                    URL url = new URL(urlstring.trim());                        
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    int response = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
```

I have one doubt if i use `URLEncode(urlstring.trim(),"UTF-8")`do i need to change my webservice code also ?

Comment: You should encode only the values of your params, not the full URL

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should encode only the values of your params:

```
    String urlString = "http://test.com?param1=" + URLEncoder.encode(value1, "UTF-8") + "&param2=" + URLEncoder.encode(value2, "UTF-8") ;

    URL url = new URL(urlstring.trim());                        
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    int response = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
```

Comment: thank you fiddler for quick response, I was encoding complete url.

Comment: I made the same mistake with my rest service on Glassfish 5. I enconded the entire url and I got malformedUrlException, we must encode only the values of the params.