# Server returned HTTP response code: 505 for URL

Tags: java, spring

I'm getting "Server returned HTTP response code: 505 for URL" for the below code:

```
                URL url = new URL(fileLocations.get(i));
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
```

While the URL works fine when opened in browser. Also tried encoding the url, that too didn't work.

URL is : http://52.66.123.140:8080/TATADHPFILES/1239/TDH Items/149387773752120170504_113201.jpg

What may be the cause?

Comment: 505  is:  HTTP Version Not Supported.

Comment: How do I fix this?

Comment: Maybe this will help you : https://dzone.com/articles/solr-tomcat-and-http11-505

Comment: I am getting `HTTP Status 404` with the above url

Comment: @MohammedsalimShivani The URL in the question is a two liner

Comment: @DivyaNagrath is there an CRLF in the URL or only a blank?

Comment: possible dupplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625659/java-io-ioexception-server-returns-http-response-code-505?

Comment: @Jens yes, i used the whole url [http://52.66.123.140:8080/TATADHPFILES/1239/TDH/Items/149387773752120170504_113201.jpg](http://52.66.123.140:8080/TATADHPFILES/1239/TDH/Items/149387773752120170504_113201.jpg)

Comment: @Jens Only a blank

Comment: The URL is on two lines "/TATADHPFILES/1239/TDH Items/149387773752120170504_113201.jpg".  There is a space between "TDH Items"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 505 error is "HTTP Error 505 HTTP version not supported" (which may be related to "java.net. URISyntaxException : Malformed IPv6 address").

I resolved your issue by encoding (the URL), and wrapping in a URI:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    URI uri = new URI(
            "http",
            "52.66.123.140:8080",
            "/TATADHPFILES/1239/TDH Items/149387773752120170504_113201.jpg",
            "Implementation", "Java");
    URL url = uri.toURL();

    try {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);

        // --- your original code will also now work ---
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
        // ---------------------------------------

        System.out.println("tester");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I was able to set a breakpoint (using Intellij) on System.out.println("tester"); - and was able to view the img variable (displaying the "correct" image).

Your original code will also work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the root cause of the issue is that you encodes whole string instead of encoding only params :

```
 String urlString = "someurl?param1=" + URLEncoder.encode(first, "UTF-8") + "&param2=" + URLEncoder.encode(second, "UTF-8") ;
```

Comment: Where do ypu see URL Encoding in op's example

Comment: So maybe you have some spaces in your URL, use trim()

Answer (score 0):

Encode your url with URLEncoder

```
URL url = new URL(fileLocations.get(i));
String encodedURL=java.net.URLEncoder.encode(url,"UTF-8");
System.out.println(encodedURL);
```